# Check if element legally supports the src attribute or innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, nodes

Is there a way to check whether an element can display `innerHTML` or `$.html()` (like elems that have a separate closing tag) OR is an element whose is meant to have a `src` attribute according to the HTML spec such as `<img>`? I'm looking for fast/reliable way to do this via jQuery or native JavaScript.

**Edit:** According to the HTML spec, elements not designed to have inner content are called [void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element) but there are also elements like this `<iframe src=url>inner</iframe>` that are totally valid.

Comment: What does the `src` attribute has to do with `innerHTML`?

Comment: Anything can have a `src` attribute. Or an `innerHTML` property for that matter, although `innerHTML` might not do what you expect.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Nothing, though the title of the question doesn't seem to match up with the question actually being asked.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, unfortunately it is not quite clear what question is being asked here.

Comment: I think the question is answered by this: any element can technically have any attribute. You cannot return a dynamic function saying `div` cannot have `src`; a `div` *can* have an `src`, it just wouldn't do anything.

Comment: I'm trying to isolate those elems that expect a `src` attribute, such as images, iframes, audio, video, etc.

Comment: That's not possible unless you hard code it (e.g., `if (elem == 'iframe' || elem == 'img' || etc)`) or use a lookup table.

Comment: @JustinSatyr And that's probably the safest way. I found a list from the spec http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/index.html#attributes-1 (scroll down to src)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a foolproof way to do this because in Javascript, *any* element can have those attributes.
Also, as odd at it may seem, almost all HTML elements, including `<img>`, have an innerHTML attribute, even though it can't really use it!

Your best bet is to make a table that specifies what elements have what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <style>
            </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="anElementWithInnerHTML"></div>
        <img id="anElementWithInnerSRC" />

        <script>

            var div = document.getElementById("anElementWithInnerHTML");
            console.log(div.innerHTML); //Outputs ""
            console.log(div.src);       //Outputs undefined

            var img = document.getElementById("anElementWithInnerSRC");
            console.log(img.innerHTML); //Outputs "" (weird right?)
            console.log(img.src);       //Outputs ""

            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could do

```
if (typeof element.src !== 'undefined')
if (element.innerHTML ...)
```

Not totally reliable since any element could add those properties (JSON).

(thanks for the typeof fix, thief)

Comment: `element.src !== undefined` or `typeof element.src !== 'undefined'` - but you cannot compare the property itself to the string `'undefined'`!

Answer (score 2):

I found the [list of elements that (according to the spec) allow the `src` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/index.html#attributes-1):

```
 audio, embed, iframe, img, input, script, source, track, video
```

So this works to check by name:

```
function srcAllowed(tag) {
    if ( !tag ) { return false; }
    var tags = ['audio','embed','iframe','img','input','script','source','track','video'];
    return 0 <= $.inArray(tag.toLowerCase(), tags); // boolean
}
```

This works for getting the appropriate content:

```
function getContent(elem) {
    // @param  elem  is a selected element like $(this)
    // returns empty string if attr() and html() are both are falsey
    return elem.attr('src') || elem.html(); 
}
```

And this is even safer:

```
function getContentSafer(elem) {
    // @param  elem  is a selected element like $(this)
    // returns empty string if attr() and html() are both are falsey
    return srcAllowed(elem.prop('tagName')) ? (elem.attr('src') || elem.html()) : elem.html(); 
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it to work the way you wanted. Thanks for posting your solution!